# Pass dynamic id's for javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to open a group with HTML-Elements when I click on a checkbox. It works fine for one group (because then i only have one id). But if I have more groups, each group has a dynamic id (for div-tag and input-tag). This is my HTML-Code:

```
<div style="line-height: 1.7em; background-color: #eee;">
   <span style="padding-left: 8px; color: #eb8f00; font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;">
      <input style="vertical-align: middle;" id="@currentElement.sGroupId" type="checkbox" name="@currentElement.sGroupId" />
      <label for="@currentElement.sGroupId">@currentElement.sGroupName</label>
   </span>
</div>

<div style="background-color: #eee;" class="@currentElement.sGroupName">
   <!-- Dynamic content -->
</div>
```

Now i have those string which are dynamic due to my foreach loop.

@currentElement.sGroupId looks like 'idgr_12' (only the number changes)
@currentElement.sGroupName is the name of the 'Group' which I want to open (the whole name changes with every loop)

This is my Javascript Code:

```
$(function () {
   $("id from div").hide();
   $("id from input").change(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.is(":checked")) {
         $("id from div").show(250);
      }
      else {
         $("id from div").hide(250);
      }
   });
});
```

Now i get for example three groups, each with a checkbox. But when I click on one checkbox each group expands. How i get these dynamic id's in my javascript method, so that only the group with the activated checkbox expands?

Answer (score 0):

in your If body you can use relative selector like

```
$(this).parent('div').show(250)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how i have to name the id from the div and the input outside the if body?